# QGIS 3.4.5 tracing tool misses vertices

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm using QGIS 3.4.5. I'm trying to make a new polygon layer that traces the border of a polygon on another layer. The tracing tool works fine except for the last vertices. I´ll attach an image to show an example.

I've tried changing the snapping tool option to only select the layer that I would like to trace, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Is there a way to fix this? Or is there another tool that's better for what I'm trying to do?

[image: Example of tracing tool not working correctly]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sometimes necessary to add intermediate vertices while tracing. Click on the vertex after which the tool misses the snapping, and continue tracing. Also increase the tracing offset so it is able to locate the missing vertices.